# How this code change colored picture into black and white

Tags: delphi

Can somebdy explain how this code make to change a colored picture into black and white?

```
Begin
  Indeks := 3 * Kolom;
  R := PDataBaris[Indeks];
  G := PDataBaris[Indeks + 1];
  B := PDataBaris[Indeks + 2];

  Intensitas := Round(0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1141 * B);

  if Intensitas < 128 then
  begin
    p := p + 1;
    Intensitas := 0
  end;

  if Intensitas > 128 then
  begin
    h := h + 1;
    Intensitas := 255
  end;

  PDataBaris[Indeks] := Intensitas;
  PDataBaris[Indeks + 1] := Intensitas;
  PDataBaris[Indeks + 2] := Intensitas;
End;
```

Comment: It doesn't change into black and white. It converts to greyscale. A web search on that term will yield the information.

Comment: @David Heffernan And greyscale image is binarized to B/W

Comment: Not quite, @Mbo. There are *three* values used, not just two.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy It might be an error

Comment: Ok, I misread that

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a standard formula to convert RGB color to its intensity (grayscale), used in YUV model, developed  for television. [Luma coding here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)

> In the Y'UV and Y'IQ models used by PAL and NTSC, the rec601 luma (Y') component is computed as Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B

I hope that other manipulations are clear - greyscale image is binarized - light colors (high intensity value) become white, dark ones become black.

Answer (score -1):

```
Begin
  //there is an array of RGB values of a picture
  //every third value is the blue value
  Indeks := 3 * Kolom;
  R := PDataBaris[Indeks];  //red
  G := PDataBaris[Indeks + 1]; //green
  B := PDataBaris[Indeks + 2];  //blue

  //calulate brightness
  //human vision is most sensitive to green and least sensitive to blue
  Intensitas := Round(0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1141 * B);

  //convert to black/white
  //without the added = you'll have 3 values (white, gray, black)
  if Intensitas <= 128 then   
  begin
    p := p + 1;
    Intensitas := 0
  end;

  if Intensitas > 128 then
  begin
    h := h + 1;
    Intensitas := 255
  end;

  //if r=g=b you have a gray value
  //based on the code above there are only two (three) values possible:
  //black(0) and white(255) (ev. gray (128))
  PDataBaris[Indeks] := Intensitas;  //red
  PDataBaris[Indeks + 1] := Intensitas;  //green 
  PDataBaris[Indeks + 2] := Intensitas;  //blue
End;
```